# What is the difference between “home” and “house”?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Can you explain more?  I do not know when we can use them in the sentence.  Can we use them instead of each other?

> They have a beautiful home.
>   They have a beautiful house.

Comment: A chair is still a chair, even when there's no one sitting there /
But a chair is not a house, and a house is not a home /
When there's no one there to hold you tight /
And no one there you can kiss good night

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A ***home*** is a metaphysical concept of where you live. My home is in an apartment building, on the second floor. I can welcome people into my home.

A ***house*** is generally used to mean a single-family dwelling, or at least a building used exclusively for a small number of people, perhaps to include a duplex house.

In your case, "They have a beautiful home," probably more implies that they decorate well and keep it up nicely. A "beautiful house" would probably mean the building itself is fancy, without saying anything about the decorations or people or their taste.

Answer (score 8):

Your **house** is the **physical structure** made of stone/wood/brick in which you live

Your **home** is the place **where you belong**. It can be a house, an apartment, or even a society. It is more personal than a house

> They have a beautiful house

could mean that the house **looks** nice, perhaps because it's expensive or is well decorated

> They have a beautiful home

could mean that it **feels** nice at their place, maybe because the people living there are a nice family or it's a peaceful neighborhood

Answer (score 3):

The term home typically refers to a more intimate description of a dwelling.  A quote about this is "It takes hands to build a house, but only hearts can build a home" (I cannot find an author for that quote).  Home is some place special to you; a house is what the neighbors live in.  In your example question, either use is acceptable in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

From Google Search:

---

> **house**
>
> *noun*
>
> A building for human habitation, especially one that is lived in by a family or small group of people.
>
> ---
>
> **home**
>
> *noun*
>
> The place where one lives permanently, especially as a member of a family or household.

---

A house is a singluar building - it can hold many or one (Or none if unowned or unoccupied) people.  A home *can be* a house, but it can also refer to any place that a person lives in a permanent manner (An apartment/flat, a duplex, a trailer, or even more abstractly a "home" city or a "home" country).

Relationally, a house can be a home, but a home is not always a house.

Comment: A house may not be a home (eg if it is derelict)

Answer (score 0):

Home is just anything which you can consider to be your place: for example, a tree, an iceberg, etc., whereas a house is a physical structure which is built by us: a treehouse, an igloo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Home:
Generally used as a term to describe a HOUSE with a family or people living in it:

> The family sits around the fire in their home.

It also generally describes the contents for example in this sentence a home would not be cozy without its contents or people, yet we would still say :

> The home was very cozy.

House:
Generally used to describe the building itself:

> The house was up for sale on the market.

Thanks, hope this helps!

Comment: The word "generally" really needs to be underscored here.